# Security Spring - Found 302

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

So, I have problem with that when I open localhost/myApp/* it always redirect to localhost/myApp/login with 302 Found Error. I'm beginner of spring.
It's my  web.xml file :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

        <display-name>SpringTest</display-name>


        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>


        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
                /WEB-INF/spring/securityContext.xml
                </param-value>
        </context-param>



        <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>



        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>ContextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
            </init-param>

            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>


        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

    </web-app>
```

It's my securityContext.xml

```
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
                 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">


        <http auto-config="true">
            <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
            <intercept-url pattern="/resources**" access="permitAll"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/images**" access="permitAll"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('USER')"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/admin_panel/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>


            <form-login
                    login-page="/login"
                    default-target-url="/"
                    authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
                    username-parameter="ssoId" password-parameter="password"/>

            <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
            <csrf/>
        </http>

        <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

        <authentication-manager >
            <authentication-provider>
                <user-service>
                    <user name="bill"  password="abc123"  authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                    <user name="admin" password="root123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                    <user name="dba"   password="root123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_DBA" />
                </user-service>
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>

    </beans:beans>
```

And my Controller :

```
package com.program.Controllers;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Created by mgrzesiuk on 24.07.16.
 */
@Controller
public class SecurityController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showLoginForm()
    {
        return "login";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null){
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Access_Denied", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String accessDeniedPage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("user",getPrincipal());
        return "accessDenied";
    }

    private String getPrincipal(){
        String userName = null;
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
            userName = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        } else {
            userName = principal.toString();
        }
        return userName;
    }


}
```

Comment: Try to add<intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />

Comment: Thank you, now everything it's ok.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer was useful to you, then you can accept the same by click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.